# Support under brick or stone facade

Tags: siding, masonry

We're renovating a pier and beam house with a concrete ring wall that supports the outer walls. The existing walls are finished with vertically installed wood panels, approx 12" x 8', which lap over the ring wall slightly at the bottom. IOW - the outside of the ring wall is flush with the stud wall.

I'm going to be replacing the sheet siding, and I'd like to know what would be involved in installing a brick or stone facade.

Comment: Is the 12"X8' siding the sheet siding you refer to? "Sheet" to me refers to 4'X8' plywood or T1-11. As a mention the footing for a true brick veneer will be much more substantial. A continuous footing all around, down to the frost line for your area and 9 to 10" beyond the outside face of the frame wall. Is the concrete ring wall possibly a new footer?

Comment: Yes - I'm talking about the 12"x8' as sheets. It's covering felt(?) covered mdf weatherproofing sheets, which I'm also going to replace, but that didn't seem relevant to the question.

Comment: I had to confirm, if it was 4X8 sheets, that could be left in place and place your veneer over it, with the proper barrier between the subsiding and veneer. I did not mention before, and you may have seen it already, there are fake stone veneers that require no additional footing to apply them. It is supported by the wall, set to a metal lath nailed to the subsiding. I have installed it befrore, when done right, it is very convincing, at a much better cost.

Comment: That is definitely an interesting alternative.